# ILike query inside array of objects with TypeORM queryBuilder

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, query-builder, jsonb

I want to select rows using ilike on vin_code with queryBuilder.

My jsonb column in **task** entity named **clientData** looks like this:

```
{
    "searchData": {
        "cars": {
            "new": [{
                "id": "ff4771fb-7651-4d79-9a02-d0f9261963fa",
                "vin_code": "MR0KX8CD301906222"
            },{
                "id": "f64c95f1-cf55-449e-9961-55940280cab6",
                "vin_code": "NMTBB0BE00R120307",
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to do a search without **ilike** like this:

```
qb.orWhere(task.client_data::jsonb @> '{"searchData": {"cars": {"new": [{ "vin_code": "MR0KX8CD301906222" }]}}}');
```

I tried to do it like this, but it didn't return anything:

```
qb.orWhere('task.client_data ::jsonb @> :client_data', {
    client_data: JSON.stringify({
        searchData: {
            cars: {
                new: [
                    {
                        vin_code: ILike("MR0KX8CD301906222")
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Can you help select rows with ilike?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like:

```
qb.orWhere(`task.client_data::jsonb @@ '$.searchData.cars.new[*].vin_code like_regex "${keyword}"'`);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).